# How do I scrape a Meteor webapp?

Tags: meteor, google-apps-script, web-scraping

I have a Meteor webapp. (e.g. `http://www.merafi.com`). I want to scrape the website using Google Apps Script. I wrote a small script for this.

```
function myFunction() {
  const url = 'http://www.merafi.com';
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  return response.getContentText();
}
```

The script is used inside a Google Spreadsheet as a macro.

```
=myFunction()
```

The problem with scraping a Meteor webapp is that I get an empty body with only script tags within it. How do I get the content inside the body tag?

[image]

Comment: You need some crawler that runs the JS like phantomJS, nightmarejs or Selenium

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that in Google Apps Script. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/

Comment: Well, then either you will have to use something other than Google Apps Script, or you have a LOT of work ahead re-writing it.

Comment: @CodeChimp, can you write that as an answer ... it is not possible. I will mark it as the right answer so that it is "answered".

Comment: I think @Floo0 has more of a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some crawler like PhantomJS or NightmareJS is required to run the Meteor JS after the page is loaded. Unfortunately, Google Apps Script environment does not allow to load external dependencies / packages. The Apps Script API does not have any method which loads a page in a separate iframe / webview. This is not possible using Google Apps Script.

Thanks to @Floo and @CodeChimp for answering the question in comments.